# Mutually exclusive Radio buttons for toggling between two group boxes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I want to achieve:

1. On init () both group boxes are hidden and both GRP A and GRP B radio button enabled [ACHIEVED].
2. I click on GRP A radio button , GRP box 1 displayed GRP B radio button grayed out. [ACHIEVED].
3. Uncheck GrP A radio button GRP Box 1 hides both GRP A and B radio buttons enabled [FAILING : NOT ABLE
   TO UNCHECK THE SELECTED RADIO BUTTON].
4. Check Group Box B radio button same process happens as described above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to 'break' the concept of radio-buttons. The "GRP A" and "GRP B" buttons (assuming they are in the same 'group') will *automatically* be mutually exclusive, **so long as both are enabled** - you *have* to have one of the buttons checked (even if there are 3 or more in the same group). Thus, in your case, to **un-check** "GRP A" you will need to **check** "GRP B".

*Unless, of course, you override the default handling of those radio-buttons.*

To override the default handling, you can provide a handler for the `BN_CLICKED` message from the each of the "GRP A" and "GRP B" buttons, and explicitly set the state of both buttons to unchecked and enabled in that handler. You would also put code in that handler to hide the two groups (or show one, when appropriate).

Here's an outline of possible code, assuming your parent dialog is derived from `CDialog` and the IDs of the two radio-buttons are `IDC_GRPA` and `IDC_GRPB`:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_CONTROL(BN_CLICKED, IDC_GRPA, &MyDialog::OnClickA)
    ON_CONTROL(BN_CLICKED, IDC_GRPB, &MyDialog::OnClickB)
    //... other handlers and message map entries
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Handler for a "GRP A" button click:
void MyDialog::OnClickA()
{
    UINT checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_GRPA);
    if (checked == BST_CHECKED) {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_GRPB)->EnableWindow(TRUE); // ENABLE other button
        CheckDlgButton(IDC_GRPA, BST_UNCHECKED); // Clear this button
        CheckDlgButton(IDC_GRPB, BST_UNCHECKED); // and the other one
        // Now do the required stuff to HIDE the group boxes...
    }
    else {
        CheckDlgButton(IDC_GRPA, BST_CHECKED); // Check this button
        GetDlgItem(IDC_GRPB)->EnableWindow(FALSE); // DISABLE other button
        // Now do the required stuff to SHOW the "GrpBox 1" controls ...
    }
}

// The "OnClickB()" handler will be very similar to the above, but with the IDs 'reversed'.
```

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: I have not put the radio buttons in the same group

Comment: @Kush OK, then maybe the first part of my answer is not very relevant (but that's how radio-buttons normally work - only one of a given group is checked at any one time). But I have modified the code so that you can just check (or clear) the specific button individually.

Comment: Thanks  to add to it I would like to ask is putting Radio buttons inside a group box only option to put them in a group ?

Comment: @Kush No. If you have them inside a group-box, then they will be in the same, mutually exclusive group by default. But you can also add `WS_GROUP` to the *extended style* of **one** button in the resource definition; that will start a 'new group' for all radios up to the next one with that style (or another group-box).

Comment: Means If I intend to add two radio buttons IDC_GRPA and IDC_GRPB to a group then I should add WS_GROUP to the extended of both the radio buttons in resource definition?

Comment: You also missed a small point in your code above the radio button definition in resorce needs to be changed from BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON to  BS_RADIOBUTTON

Comment: @Kush On the first point: No! Only add the `WS_GROUP` extended style to the *first* in each group. On the second point: Yes, if you're going to override the default behaviour, it's best to take out the `AUTO`; but then, you probably don't need the `WS_GROUP` style for either button.

Comment: @Adrain Thanks for the support